# Typeahead request for remote data everytime key pressed. Is there a way to arrange preventing making parallel requests ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have the following typeahead function

```
$('.search-input').typeahead({
minLength: 3,
source: function (query, process) {
    return $.getJSON(
        '/search/search_autocomplete/',
        {query: query},
        function (data) {
            var newData = [];
            $.each(data,function(){
                newData.push(this.destination + "  (" + this.country + ")");
            });
            return process(newData)
        })

}
```

});

But everytime when I press a key after 3 chars, it goes and make a get request from server. And after a while, all the requests stuck in pending, and those parallel requests becomes a serious load for the server to response. Is there a way to arrange the parallel requests or wait for some time interval before making requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var running = 0;

$('.search-input').typeahead({
minLength: 3,
source: function (query, process) {
    if(running) return;
    running = 1; 

    return $.getJSON(
        '/search/search_autocomplete/',
        {query: query},
        function (data) {
            var newData = [];
            $.each(data,function(){
                newData.push(this.destination + "  (" + this.country + ")");
            });
            return process(newData)
        }).always(running=0);

}
```

you also could try a timeout in the alway() function: `setInterval(function(){running=0},500);`

Comment: I don't recommend the flag-based solution as you might end up displaying results which are not relevant to what the user is typing as the request may have been not made with the latest search query.